# IO::Socket::INET returns a empty socket

Tags: ios, perl, sockets

This is my code:

```
 my $server_socket = new IO::Socket::INET
            (
                LocalPort => 8378,
                Type      => SOCK_STREAM,
                Listen    => $SOMAXCONN,
                Proto     => 'tcp',
                Reuse     => 1
            ) || die "$!\n";

        $serverName   = $ENV{COMPUTERNAME};
        $socketPortNr = 8378;
        $clientSocket = new IO::Socket::INET (PeerAddr => $serverName,
                                                  PeerPort => $socketPortNr,
                                                  Proto    => 'tcp');
```

but the `$clientSocket` is empty.

What could be the reason for empty `$clientSocket`?

Comment: Always use `use warnings` and `use strict` in your code.

Comment: when I use use strict, I get errors for variable initialization and script is stopped

Comment: First declare all your variables.

Comment: the same script was running successfully in Windows 7 ultimate machine. Im facing issue in Windows 7 enterprise.So I think use strict would not be a problem.

Comment: `my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(...) or die $!`. The `$!` will tell you what's wrong

Comment: Is `$ENV{COMPUTERNAME}` pointing where you expect?  You really should at least be doing `use strict;` here, as it will help point out problems in your script.

Comment: Re "when I use use strict, I get errors for variable initialization and script is stopped", Silencing error messages (by removing `use strict; use warnings;`) does nothing to fix the errors that prompted those messages.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to speculate. As shown in the examples in its documentation, `IO::Socket::INET->new` places an error message in `$@` when it fails.

```
my $client_socket = new IO::Socket::INET->new(
   ...
)
   or die("Can't create client socket: $@\n");
```

(`$!` is also set, though the information it provides is not always as precise.)